# Its posible port to mac a electron compiled app to windows?

Tags: windows, macos, electron

Well, I am trying to port a compiled app to mac (with electron), but that app its already compiled to windows

I tried with fiddle, but I don't know. I am very beginner

I am trying to port incredibox mods to mac and I need somebody help for do it

Comment: Are you talking about https://www.incredibox.com/ ? There is a Windows version listed on their download page - can't you use that? If not I'd suggest talking with the company directly.

Comment: Beyond the legal issues, doing what you want is likely to be very hard without access to the source. Electron app source can't be completed hidden, but it can be obfuscated enough to make it almost completely unhelpful.  Of course if you have the original source code, then it becomes much easier.